# What's regular expression for this case in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

all
I have some strings to find like below

```
\r\n1928A\r\n
\r\nabc\r\n
\r\n239\r\n
```

What is the best way to find those strings in a sentence?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: what do you want `\r`,`\n` or only `n1928A` and what have you tried

Comment: is the word always  in betweem \r\n word\r\n ....

Comment: @pratapk yes, exactly

Comment: @Anirudh I want the whole word including \r\n in the both sides.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex

```
\r?\n\w+\r?\n
```

In case you have only 1 `\r?\n` between words...you can use this regex

```
\r?\n\w+(?=\r?\n)
```

---

`\w` would match a single digit,alphabet or `_`

`+` is quantifier which matches preceding pattern 1 to many times

So, `\w+` would match  1 to many words

`?` would match the preceding pattern optionally..

So,with `\r?` we would match \r optionally

---

Your code would be

```
List<String> lst=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(x.Value)
                      .ToList();
```

Or to make it more clear

```
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input,regex))
{
    m.Value;
}
```

Comment: I like you explain also the content of your given regex :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the word you want to match, is **always** between two `\r\n`, you may want to use [`string.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) instead of a Regex:

```
string input = @"hello\r\nhow\r\nare\r\nyou?";
string[] words = input.Split(@"\r\n", StringSplitOptions.None);
// words == { "hello", "how", "are", "you?" }

if (words.Length >= 3)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
    // first and last elements ("hello" and "you?") are not between new lines
    {
        string word = @"\r\n" + words[i] + "\r\n";
        // do something with your words "how" and "are"
    }
}
```